# Подходящий контрол для отображения B-дерева

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Здравствуйте.
Есть b-дерево, хотелось бы отобразить его структуру в winForms либо wpf без особых затрат. Может кто-то знает наиболее подходящий контрол для решения это задачи?

Вот [пример](http://ats.oka.nu/b-tree/b-tree.manual.html), как все это дело должно выглядеть.

Comment: Вручную... Пока даже найти не получается готовый элемент управления...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть пакет для рисования графов [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). В нём Вы можете нарисовать свой граф(вернее написать связи между узлами), а отобразить этим элементом управления [Dot2WPF - a WPF control for viewing Dot graphs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18870/Dot2WPF-a-WPF-control-for-viewing-Dot-graphs).

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает использовать для всего графа Canvas, для узлов Ellipse, для рёбер Line? Вычислять координаты вручную (да это и не так сложно).

Ваш случай очень уж экзотический, чтобы для него было решение "из коробки".